# Xcode won't add bundle resources

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to make sure that certain resources get copied as **Bundle Resources** when my iOS app gets built inside of Xcode.

When I select my target, go to **Build Phases**, expand the **Copy Bundles Resources** accordion pane and click the "+" icon I see:

[image]

So far so good. However, I want to select the **Models.scnassets** folder under my **Resources** folder, and add everything inside of it. But Xcode won't let me select the whole **Models.scnassets** folder, only its contents.

Perhaps I need to refactor the **Models.scnassets** folder to be a special type of folder first?

Either way, what's the solution here: how do I add the entire **Models.scnassets** folder as a bundled resource?

Comment: They look like group references.  You can try making them folder references.

Comment: Thanks @Calimari328 (+1) how do I make the yellow `Models.scnassets` folder turn into a blue "folder reference"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you shift+click and select all under folder? That or make it a folder reference rather than a group. (blue folder not brown folder)

I was able to make a folder reference by doing the following:

1. Make a folder somewhere (for instance I just made it on my Desktop) called what you want your folder in Xcode to be (for you that would be **Models.scnassets**). It may give you a warning about becoming a single file, just click ok.
2. Add in whatever assets you want (I just did some random pictures)
3. Drag and drop that folder into your Xcode, ensuring the `Create folder references` option is selected (See Image):

[image]

Now you should be able to click on only that folder to add to your **Bundle Resources**

Comment: Yes, thanks @CodeNinja (+1)...how do I make the folder blue (a so-called "folder reference")?